# BrowserExtension webRequest.onBeforeRequest return promise

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have the following in a Chrome and FireFox extension:

```
function webListener(requestDetails) {
    var asyncCancel = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve({ cancel : true });
    });
    return asyncCancel;
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    webListener, {
        urls: ["<all_urls>"],
        types: ["script"]
    }, ["blocking", "requestBody"]
);
```

The problem is that it doesn't cancel the request. I read Chrome docs and Firefox docs and for Firefox it says it's based on Chrome's API and can return a promise to handle the request asynchronously..

However, unless I make it synchronous, it fails to cancel (IE: If I return just `{cancel : true}` instead of the promise, it works).

Am I doing something wrong or does Chrome and Firefox only support synchronous request handling here?

Comment: docs link?.....

Comment: @mehulmpt; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest . The part that says: `From Firefox 52 onwards, instead of returning BlockingResponse, the listener can return a Promise which is resolved with a BlockingResponse. This enables the listener to process the request asynchronously.`  I am using Firefox Quantum which is the latest browser out and the latest Chrome.

Comment: I think it makes sense why your code is not working. The docs listed the example where the Promise redirects the requests. Browser does not stop the request if your handle is asynchronous. You can only redirect from a returned promise, not cancel it

Comment: Also, the Chrome documentation itself doesn't mention *anything* about supporting a promise instead of a direct `BlockingResponse`, so I wouldn't assume it will work. I know the Firefox docs say they are based on Chrome, but that was just for initial design, and there has probably been some divergence.

Comment: @mehulmpt; Hmm I assumed since it said `process the request asynchronously`, that it meant cancel and redirect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Chrome documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) reads to me as though you **must** use a synchronous, blocking response to cancel a request, and that has been my experience also.

Emphasis mine :

> If the optional opt_extraInfoSpec array contains the string 'blocking'
>   (only allowed for specific events), the callback function is handled
>   synchronously. That means that the request is blocked until the
>   callback function returns. **In this case**, the callback can return a
>   webRequest.BlockingResponse that determines the further life cycle of
>   the request. Depending on the context, **this response allows cancelling
>   or redirecting a request** (onBeforeRequest), cancelling a request or
>   modifying headers (onBeforeSendHeaders, onHeadersReceived), and
>   cancelling a request or providing authentication credentials
>   (onAuthRequired).

My reading is that you can only influence the request lifetime(like cancelling it) if your event handler is synchronous.

Furthermore, the docs also don't mention anything about supporting a Promise instead of a BlockingResponse directly, so it seems that that is Firefox-specific functionality.

Comment: If I put a `console.log` in the promise for both Chrome and Firefox, it gets printed, everything works except the actual cancelling. I guess you're right, it must be synchronous.

Comment: Chrome API doesn't use Promise anywhere. See also [Chrome incompatibilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities) article on MDN.

Comment: `it seems that that is Firefox-specific functionality.` For Firefox, I'm leaning closer to saying it's more of what the code looks like that is unknown.