# Making synchoronous XHR request with chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking to make a Chrome extension that hooks in to `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` to determine whether or not to block the current page request. As a result, I need to make a request to an API to determine it.

Is there a good way to make the `checkUrl` request synchronous to satisfy the requirements of `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`?

```
function checkUrl(url, callback) {
  let api    = 'http://localhost:9000/filter';
  let data   = {
    url: url,
  };

  let json = JSON.stringify(data);

  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', api, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Bark-Email', email);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      callback(xhr.response);
    }
  }
  xhr.send(json);
}

function onBeforeRequestHandler(details) {
  let url = new URL(details.url);

  console.log(details.type, ": ", url.host)

  checkUrl(url, function(resp) {
    let status      = resp.status;
    let redirectUrl = resp.redirect_url;

    if (status == "allowed") {
      return { cancel: false }; // <<<<<  This doesn't work b/c of the callback
    } else {
      return { redirectUrl: redirectUrl };
    }
  });
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(onBeforeRequestHandler,
  {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"],
    types: ["sub_frame", "main_frame", "xmlhttprequest"]
  },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: `From Firefox 52 onwards, instead of returning BlockingResponse, the listener can return a Promise which is resolved with a BlockingResponse. This enables the listener to process the request asynchronously.` ~ [MDN, onRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest)

Comment: You will need a synchronous call, and checking a remote resource will always be async. Afaik, all you can do is poll the resource and cache the result in memory, then test the last in memory value.

Comment: Alternatively, couldn't you redirect to your server and tunnel all requests through it, like a VPN?

Comment: @JonasWilms I didn't know about that. Is this something that's available cross-browser?

Comment: @steven dunno, just googled that API and found that, never written any browser extension.

Comment: @StevenStark - I think it's a mozilla enhancement - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910732/browserextension-webrequest-onbeforerequest-return-promise

Comment: Replace true with false in xhr.open() and it'll become synchronous so you'll be able to use xhr.response immediately after xhr.send() without the need for onreadystatechange. Naturally, you'll switch checkUrl to a direct return of the value instead of using the callback mechanism.

Comment: @wOxxOm I ended up doing just this and worked great. It does throw a deprecation warning about blocking the main thread, but not sure how much I should care since that's the intent anyway, as long as its supported.

Answer (score 0):

I swapped:

```
  xhr.open('POST', api, true);
```

for

```
  xhr.open('POST', api, false);
```

and that makes the request synchronous. Then returned the result from the xhr request and use that inline:

```
  return JSON.parse(xhr.response);
```